# How to automatically assign uploaded image to user?

Tags: django, image, foreign-keys

I am new to django and try to make a simple image uplad app, where users can upload images.

Here are the parts:

model.py

```
class UserPic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    picfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_uplaod_file_name)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        picform = PicForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if picform.is_valid():

            newpic = UserPic(picfile = request.FILES['picfile'])
            newpic = picform.save(commit=False)
            newpic.user = request.user
            newpic.save()
            message = "file %s is uploaded" % newpic #**returns name of current user instead of the file's name**
            userpics = UserPic.objects.all()
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return render_to_response('userpics/listpics.html',
                                      {'userpics': userpics, 'picform': picform},
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

forms.py

```
class PicForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
                model= UserPic
                fields = ( 'picfile',)
```

listpic.html

```
<p> Upload pics to your gallery </p>
{% if userpics %}
        <ul>
        {% for pic in userpics %}
            <li><a href="{{ pic.picfile.url }}">{{ pic.picfile.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No userpics.</p>
    {% endif %}

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="/add-pic/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

<ul>
{{picform.as_ul}}
</ul>
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>
```

Upade: As per suggestion , I modified the views and the error is gone but the file is not being saved into database.

Basically my problem is how to automatically assign user as the foreign key.
I try several different solutions. but still got stock on this and appreciate your help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a new object. For `commit=False` to work, you should be using the `ModelForm` object. Whereas, you are creating the model object from the class directly, hence the error.

Try something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    picform = PicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if picform.is_valid():
        newpic = picform.save(commit=False)
        newpic.user= request.user #user would be undefined. 
        newpic.save()
    #rest of the code.
```

Read more on [django-modelforms here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). [THe `save()` method in particular](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: After adding picform I get 'global name 'user' is not defined'.

Comment: exactly. check the comment. it should be `request.user`

Comment: Sorry, the errors are gone but no image is saved as I check the database. 'newpic' seem to have been turn into a user object, since when I write it as a string, it prints the current user name. There is something wrong here.

Comment: that is because you might have a `__unicode__` attribute on the `UserPic` model.

Comment: I have deleted __unicode__ but the problem persists. a print statement like "file %s is uploaded" % newpic gives me name of the user instead of name of the file.

Comment: Is this a  typo? `get_uplaod_file_name` ?

Comment: no, it is small function to rename the image file. It works fine elsewhere to create thumbnails for users.

Comment: Ok. Everything looks good. However you can look into 2 things: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7264836/1628832 and 2. See if PIL or Pillow libraries you are using are functioning accurately.

Comment: oh at last I figured out. I needed to remove 'instance=request.user'.

Comment: Please modify the answer (remove instance...) so that I can choose your answer.